# Can value of a variable change in a asynchronous program?

Tags: java, asynchronous

```
String errorState = "value";
ComplexObj complexObj = getComplexObj();
complexObj.setErrorState(errorState);
// do async task
if(errorState){ 
   doSomething();
}
else{
   doSomethingElse();
}
```

Can it happen that, because of async task, value of errorState could have got reset ?

Comment: Is this question being asked to confirm/rule out a possible cause of behavior you've observed but not described? "because of async tasK" can mean many things. Just switching threads doesn't change data. The code has to, but again that depends on the code and the data too.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two questions here - one in the title and the other in the body

> Can value of a variable change in a asynchronous program?

Yes, an asynchronous process may alter a shared resource if that resource is mutable.

> Can it happen that, because of async task, value of errorState could
> have got reset ?

No, Strings are immutable in Java so `errorState` cannot be altered by the asynchronous process.  The reference within the asynchronous process may be pointed at another String but the original reference is still pointing to the original object which is unperturbed.